# Estimate on Limit of Recursive Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, estimation

How can I estimate (via a lower bound) the limit of the recursive sequence
$$P_{n+1}=P_n-\frac{C(P_n-1)^2}{(2^n+C)(P_n+C2^{-n})}$$
where $0<C<1$ and $1<P_0<2$. Let $P_{\infty}=\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n$. The best estimate I can get is
$$\begin{aligned}
P_{\infty}-P_0 &=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{C(P_n-1)^2}{(2^n+C)(P_n+C2^{-n})} \\
&> -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{C(P_n-1)^2}{2^nP_n} \\
&> -\frac{(P_0-1)^2}{P_0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{C}{2^n}
\end{aligned}$$
where from line 2 to 3 I use the fact that $(P_n)$ is decreasing. Hence
$$P_{\infty}> P_0-2C\frac{(P_0-1)^2}{P_0}$$
This is a fairly decent bound when looking at the absolute difference, but for my application I need as much precision as possible so I'm hoping to find a better lower bound. Special functions are acceptable if they arise.

**Edit**:
As per Wolfram, we have that
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{C(P_0-1)^2}{(2^n+C)(P_0+C2^{-n})} \\
=&\frac{P_0-1}{\ln(2)}\Big(\psi_2(\log_2(-1/C))-\psi_2(\log_2(-P_0/C))\Big)
\end{aligned}$$
which gives
$$P_{\infty}>P_0-\frac{P_0-1}{\ln(2)}\Big(\psi_2(\log_2(-1/C))-\psi_2(\log_2(-P_0/C))\Big)$$

Comment: So how is the second bound you obtained? You still need something better?

Comment: @YuriyS I think the second bound would be good enough, however I realized I evaluated it wrong. The limit appears harder to calculate.

Comment: I have tried to find your last limit with Mathematica and it gave me $0$ (no matter which value $P_0$ takes)

Comment: @YuriyS Doing it by hand I get $0$ independent of $P_0$, however using WolframAlpha I do not get $0$. I also don't see how the imaginary parts of the terms would cancel if it were $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a limit, it is a fixed point of your recurrence, i.e. a solution to
$$P = P − \frac{C (P − 1)^2}{(2^n + C) (P + C \cdot 2^{−n})}$$
This is a quadratic equation.

Comment: What about $2^n$ and $2^{-n}$?